# Windows Performance Analyzer crashes

Tags: etw, xperf, windows-performance-analyzer

I have successfully used the WPRUI and WPA applications in the past, the last time a month ago, to identify performance problems in our C++ applications. But today I recorded a new trace of one of them, and open it just to see WPA crashing.
It's reproducible every time by opening an ETL and going to Graph Explorer -> Computation -> CPU Usage (sampled) -> unfold. Just clicking to see the CPU sampled graph list. Sometimes it crashes silently, sometimes with the dialog that lets you debug the crash.
Has anybody experienced problems like this? I don't see any support forum in the Windows Performance Toolkit site, and I would like of course to find a solution for this. Any hints are greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

PS: reinstalling doesn't help. Neither does removing user preferences. The stack only showed me a problem accessing memory out of bounds, in a "Task" class, but I can't get the debug dialog to show again (it's crashing silently now, every time).

PS2: the only significant change I remember to have done in this past month is installing the CTP of Visual Studio 2015, and letting Windows upgrade a bunch of packages it had pending (I'm in a capped subnetwork and Windows doesn't upgrade automatically).

Comment: create a crash dump, open it in Windbg, run **!analyze -v** and post the output here.

Comment: have you tried to open that Etl file on another machin?

Comment: I sent the ETL file to a colleague and the crashing happens for him as well. Also, this is the output of running !analyze -v in windbg for the dump (it's too verbose and doesn't fit in the amount of characters that this box will allow me, so it's in pastebin)
[http://pastebin.com/t4ukrcg1](http://pastebin.com/t4ukrcg1)

Comment: can you share the ETL or does it contain any "secrets"? Which WPA version and which Windows version do you use?

Comment: The 7z-compressed ETW is under: http://wikisend.com/download/407656/demoproject.7z
WPA reports version 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623). OS is Windows 7 SP1, currently with all updates installed.

Comment: A colleague has submitted a bug report to Microsoft. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1254590/wpa-crashes-when-expanding-cpu-usage-sampled-node . I don't really know what to do as a workaround the issue, other that not trying to display the sampled CPU graph.

Comment: I can open the ETL file with WPA.exe (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5749744/Bilder/stackoverflow/LeCoc/WPA_CPU_Sampling.png) and the older xperfview.exe fine. Which issue do you want to trace with xperf/WPA?

Comment: Can you unfold the "Computation -> CPU Usage (Sampled)" element on the left menu? So far, the two machines that we've used to profile have the same problem (i.e. the original reported problem).

Comment: yes, this works fine: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5749744/Bilder/stackoverflow/LeCoc/WPA_CPU_Sampling_2.png I can also see that you use the original 8.1 WPT. There was an update in November 2014. Try the new version: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891

Comment: I have just tried with the new version, and the issue remains. I'm now uninstalling anything related to the Windows SDK and ensuring no wpa is around, to freshly install the latest version.

Comment: VS2015 CTP installs a .net 4.6 pre-release version. Maybe this .net versions causes the issue. I use .net 4.5.2

Comment: I have uninstalled 4.6 (and after a little repairing of VS2013) wpa seems to work again, as before. If you put your last comment as answer, I'll accept it as the solution. Many thanks.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS2015 CTP installs a [.Net 4.6 pre-release version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#v46). Maybe this .net versions causes the issue. So remove VS2015 CTP and the .Net 4.6 Preview and reinstall [.Net 4.5.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642).